# GRASS r.watershed problems in QGIS 2.12

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I have a weird error when using r.watershed in QGIS and I have depleted all my ideas.

Yesterday it was working normally and generating all the files, then suddenly it stopped working and shows the message:

> The following layers were not correctly created:
>    Number of cells which drain to each cell
>    Direction of the drainage and so on...

I have tried reinstalling the application, re-installing a new version, using GRASS 7 instead of 6, using other DEM, changing the location of the DEM, changing the reference system of the DEM, and the result remains the same.

In addition I should mention that other GRASS algorithms work normally and I get outputs (I had not tried all of them).

Also, before the problem presented, the application started 'mini-dumping' when closing.